# Codeigniter - Implode-generated Query returns "Unknown column"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently trying to write a query in codeigniter, I'm having a problem including and implode inside the query. This is my code.

```
$permitedCodeList = ["ELEC-22", "ELEC-100", "ELEC-200", "999873"];

$query = $this->inventario_db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM pt_inv_num_id_equipo
    WHERE numID = '123456789' AND codigo IN ('" . implode("','", $permitedCodeList). "')
    LIMIT 1
");
$result = $query->row();
```

I'm getting the following error message: `Unknown column 'ELEC' in 'where clause'`. I know it has todo with the implode returning the data as `ELEC-22,ELEC-100,ELEC-200,999873` but it doesn't seem to add a single quote to each value and include it in the query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code (just the part generating the SQL, not the query itself) and the generated SQL looks fine - no bust quotes, no truncated `codigo` values. Is there really nothing else to your code than what you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could use [CI Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)
It specifically has `where_in` method to handle such scenario.

Your query can be constructed as below:

```
        $permitedCodeList = ["ELEC-22", "ELEC-100", "ELEC-200", "999873"];

        $this->db->from('pt_inv_num_id_equipo');
        $this->db->where('numID ', 1234 );
        $this->db->where_in('codigo', $permitedCodeList );
        $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

You could also debug the last query using below code

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I was thinking of using the CI Query Builder, but I wanted to see if I could get it working without the query builder. But I guess the best thing to do is use the builder in this scenario. Thanks for your answer, it worked. :)

Comment: @BrianMoreno Glad it worked. Thanks for accepting the answer. Could you please also upvote the answer. Cheers!